# When is it necessary to bind parameters with MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysqli, prepared-statement

From this code I received an error.

```
//Prepare insert statement.
if($InsertEventQuery = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into events(eventname, eventdesc, eventmonth, eventdate, eventyear, eventstart, eventend) VALUES ('$EventName','$EventDesc','$EventMonth','$EventDate','$EventYear','$EventStart','$EventEnd')"))
{
    //Bind parameters of insert statement.
    $InsertEventQuery->bind_param('ssiiiii', $EventName, $EventDesc, $EventMonth, $EventDate, $EventYear, $EventStart, $EventEnd);
```

This is the error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in[...]

I looked into it because the error appears to be incorrect and found:

[PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865151/php-warning-mysqli-stmtbind-param-number-of-variables-doesnt-match-number)

> You do not need to bind parameters in this case. Placeholders are used for the values in an INSERT statement, or in a WHERE clause. (Note that placeholders are not allowed for identifiers, such as the column names in your statement.)

This confused me and I am now wondering in interest of security, when is it necessary to bind parameters and when is it necessary to use placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding parameters is a good idea in any INSERT statement as it will prevent SQL injection, and will also sanitize your strings for free.

I usually get it working using question mark in prepare statement like this:

```
//Prepare insert statement.
if ($InsertEventQuery = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into events(eventname, eventdesc, eventmonth, eventdate, eventyear, eventstart, eventend) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
    //Bind parameters of insert statement.
    $InsertEventQuery->bind_param('ssiiiii', $EventName, $EventDesc, $EventMonth, $EventDate, $EventYear, $EventStart, $EventEnd);
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. I see now that putting variable names in the prepare() statement and the bind_param() statement is redundant but then I don't understand why the question marks are necessary.

Comment: Actually, this is from the doc : _This parameter can include one or more parameter markers in the SQL statement by embedding question mark (?) characters at the appropriate positions._ [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php]

Comment: Well, I don't quite understand it but it works now.  Thanks a lot!