# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I don't know why this is happening and I keep getting this error Warning:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID ='$ID'");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($clicks); // Store the result in the $clicks variable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: mysqli\_stmt::bind\_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865151/php-warning-mysqli-stmtbind-param-number-of-variables-doesnt-match-number)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `'$ID'` in the query with `?`. The question mark is used to mark variables that need to be bound.

Comment: @Enstage Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference